# Given the resoult of a GROUP operation how can I store each nested-bag in a folder named after the group?

Tags: apache-pig

I've a relation D:

```
grunt> DESCRIBE D;
D: {i: int,l: chararray}
```

on which a GROUP is applied:

```
grunt> G = group D by i;
grunt> illustrate G;
-------------------------------------
| D     | i:int    | l:chararray    |
-------------------------------------
|       | 1        | B              |
|       | 1        | A              |
|       | 2        | A              |
-------------------------------------

-----------------------------------------------------------------------
| G     | group:int    | D:bag{:tuple(i:int,l:chararray)}             |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|       | 1            | {(1, B), (1, A)}                             |
|       | 2            | {(2, A)}                                     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I store each nested bag `G.D` in a file named as the corresponding group? I.e. `/ouput/1`, `/output/2`

I understand I can't use a `store` operation in a `foreach` block. In fact the following doeasn't work:

```
grunt> foreach G { store D into '/output/' + ((chararray) group) }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MultiStorage()` option will work for you. It will be available in `piggybank jar.` You need to download from this link http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/p/Downloadpiggybankjar.htm and set it in your classpath.

**Example:**
**input**

```
1,A
1,B
2,A
```

**PigScript:**

```
REGISTER '/tmp/piggybank.jar';

A = LOAD 'input' USING PigStorage(',') AS (i:int,l:chararray);
B = GROUP A BY i;
STORE B INTO 'output' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.MultiStorage('output', '0');
```

Now `output` folder contains 2 dirs named 1 and 2 where the corresponding group value will be stored inside this folder.

**Output:**

```
output$ ls
1       2       _SUCCESS
```

**Reference:**
https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/MultiStorage.html

Comment: Accepted as it seems to answer the question I made, but I havent actually tested it.